# when does getItemCount() method get called in RecycleView adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a adapter which populates data to `RecyclerView`.

I am not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and I am setting the adapter to the `RecyclerView` in `onCreateView()` (so in `getItemCount()` should be called once)  in Fragment but I find `getItemCount()` called multiple times.

Comment: "when does getItemCount() method get called in RecycleView adapter?" -- whenever the `RecyclerView` wants. You should not be making any assumptions about how many times `getItemCount()` will be called. Focus on ensuring that `getItemCount()` is fast, and the number of times that it is called will not matter.